# Setting sqlcmd variable using tsql variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd

It seems like this approach for setting `sqlcmd` variable does not work so I am wondering if there is another way?

```
DECLARE @d varchar(max);
SET @d = 'foobar';

:setvar database @d
USE $(database)
```

**Note:** I realized that using `:setvar` in this manner works but I want to set it using a variable in the T-SQL script instead of explicitly setting it.

```
:setvar database "foobar"
```

Answer (score 1):

This makes no logical sense, from the perspective of SQLCMD. `:setvar` is a command that lives outside the T-SQL script; it can't "see" anything the T-SQL script does at runtime. You can set the variable through [any number of means](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms188714), including environment variables, options and `:setvar` itself, but you can't mix in runtime T-SQL execution.

Rethink your script so the SQLCMD script lives "outside" the T-SQL script, and the T-SQL script does the necessary runtime actions. Since you can execute dynamic statements in T-SQL, there shouldn't be any need for setting an SQLCMD variable through T-SQL rather than the other way around.